# C# multiple inheritance, using protected member

Tags: c#, multiple-inheritance, protected

I have little problem using inheritance. I can neither change the value of first and second in class C nor first in class B when they are protected. If these variables are public everything works fine, but in this case what's the point of using protected?

```
class A
{
    protected int first { get; set; }
}

class B : A
{
    protected int second { get; set; }

    public Show() 
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.first = 5;
    }
}

class C : B
{
    private int third { get; set; }

    static void Main()
    {
        B b = new B();
        b.first = 1;
        b.second = 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need them to be public, then they have to be public.  End of story.  It's not clear what you really want from this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is simply caused by you putting your program's entry point inside the class you want to test. Because `Main()` is static, you can't access `C`'s (inherited) instance members.

So separate it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        C c = new C();
        c.Test();
    }
}
```

Your class `C` inherits from `B`, so `C` can access `B`'s protected members like so:

```
class C : B
{
    private int third { get; set; }

    public void Test()
    {
        first = 1; // from A
        second = 2; // from B
        third = 3; // from C
    }
}
```

By `new`ing a `B` inside `C`, there's no relation between those instances of `B` and `C`, so all you can access there are `B`'s `public` and `internal` members.

Comment: Thanks, i realize that writing for example a.first=5; was wrong. when using protected first=5 is only needed. stupid mistake:)

Answer (score 1):

You're allowed to access the protected members when you're dealing with instances of your own class:

```
class B :A
{
    protected int second { get; set; }

    public show() {
        this.first = 5; //This is valid
    }
}
```

If you were allowed arbitrary access to your base class' `protected` members, on *any* instance of the base class, this would be allowed:

```
class DDefinitelyNotB : A
{
}

class B :A
{
    protected int second { get; set; }

    public show() {
        A a = new DDefinitelyNotB ();
        a.first = 5;
    }
}
```

And that could be bad for `DDefinitelyNotB`, which isn't expecting *other* classes that just happen to derive from `A` to be able to interfere with the `protected` members it's inherited from `A`.